# Using an Excel Macro to identify and then filter out specific rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've been attempting to create a macro to grab certain rows in my excel sheet to no avail. Here's what I am looking at before.

**I need to find the wording "Car result printed - (Car Name)"(shown under A2) and grab the content RIGHT below it and than paste that content to another column.** As the second photo shows, F-150 was properly pasted into another column. Instead of a single instance this would have hundreds obviously.

I tried using a variety of macros, but kept getting stonewalled (probably because my lack of VBA). Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you all.

[image: Before]

[image]

Comment: Is it always the same criteria to choose the cell?

Comment: In B2 `=if(A2="Car result printed - (Car Name)", A3, "")` and fill down